# Duvida sobre ponteiros de ponteiros e retorno de funções

Tags: c, ponteiro, funções, árvore-binária

Olá, pessoal. Eu gostaria de saber por que a função abaixo precisaria de um ponteiro pra ponteiro, no caso um `**root`, para que a linha /1/
pudesse modificar o `*root`, enquanto a linha  /2/ consegue modificá-lo sem precisar recorrer a  isso. Qual a diferença entre:

```
root->right = remover(root->right,valor);
```

e

`root = NULL;`?

Os dois não estão tentando modificar o ponteiro sem utilizar um ponteiro pra ponteiro? Logo, os dois não deveriam estar errados?

FUNÇÃO:

```
Node * remover(Node *root, int valor){
if(root == NULL){
cout<<"Elemento não encontrado."<<endl; 
}
else{
if(root->data == valor){
    root = NULL;
    cout<<"Elemento removido!"<<endl;
    return root;
}
if(root->data > valor){
    /* 1 */ //remover(root->left,valor); não funciona
    /* 2 */root->left = remover(root->left,valor); // funciona
    return root;
}
if(root->data < valor){
    /* 1 */ //remover(root->right,valor);  não funciona
    /* 2 */root->right = remover(root->right,valor); // funciona        
    return root;        
}
}
}
```

Comment: Onde você está vendo ponteiro de ponteiro? Não entendi qual é a dúvida. Sem ver o todo, me parece que o código está certo.

Comment: Eu disse que, se ao invés de `*root` eu tivesse usado `**root`, o programa funcionaria com a linha /1/ também. Eu só queria entender por que a linha 2 funciona, mesmo utilizando apenas um ponteiro simples, `*root`.

Comment: A função devia ser void não há razão para editar uma variável e retorná-lá.

Answer (score 0):

A primeira linha está modificando `root->right` e não `root`. A prova disso é que, se você exibir na tela o endereço de `root` antes e depois dessa operação, não haverá mudança.

A segunda linha tenta mudar (julgando pela semântica) o valor salvo no ponteiro `root`. Para mudar esse valor do lado de dentro de uma função, tal função precisa do endereço da variável que contém esse valor.

Lembre-se: `root` guarda simplesmente um endereço de memória. Mudar o que está no lugar apontado por esse endereço não é o mesmo que mudar o esse endereço.

Comment: então, de certa forma, o `root` está agindo como um ponteiro de ponteiro, na linha 2, já que ele está modificando um ponteiro que está dentro dele, no caso `right`? Seria certo pensar dessa forma?

Comment: Não acho que é bom ficar pensando nas nuances semânticas das coisas assim quando existe uma resposta objetiva: através de root é possível alcançar right e mudar o valor, simplesmente porque o valor de right está "dentro" de root. Talvez fique mais claro se você retirar o operador seta e trocar pelos devidos asteriscos até ficar bem claro (depois, coloque a seta de volta)